# how to run game server

Tags: c++, udk, server

I'm creating a game on UDK and i have some questons about the server. my game is a 3d mmorpg simliar to dayz/warz. I have some questions

Each map will consist of  30-60 players similar to dayz/ warz. should i use cloud servers or should i go for dedicated server?

should I get a server that can hold hundreds of players or should I host multiple servers for each instances(map)?

also what should the specs be for the server if I'am looking to host 200 players per server?
how do other games make a profit from server hosting.. from what i know it would cost me around £80/month to host a server for 200 players. my game cost $20/£15 so 200 x £15 equals 3000. 3000- (80 x 12 months) equals 3000 - 960 which is 2040. does that mean if you buy my game I can only host for a year. how does minecraft,warz  manage to keep their servers running without additional income for years?

Comment: This question might be too broad for the site. But to answer one of your questions, most games charge people for servers.

Comment: AFAIK Minecraft and WarZ servers are run by users.

Comment: so once the player buy the game, they also have to buy server space

Comment: I agree this question is too broad; voted to close.

Comment: Just release a dedicated server applications so your players may host and run them. If the game is good and a lot of users run their servers, you can stop paying for your own servers, as they won't be needed any more.

Answer (score 3):

If your game has high demands for server hardware/bandwidth you have a few options:

- Require players to pay to use your servers, either via monthly fees or a pay as you go system.
- Run the servers at a loss, if enough people continue to buy the game you can continue to run the servers.
- Run the servers with some form of advertising to offset the costs.
- Allow players to create their own servers.
- Some combination of the above.

Companies that run servers are not doing so "without additional income for years". Once the money stops, the servers stop too. Consider a server option that allows you to scale your needs, like [Amazon Cloud services](http://aws.amazon.com/). The requirements of your server will depend entirely on the requirements of your game, the number of users connecting and the quality of connection you desire.